# What is the logical reasoning behind the substitution of trigonometric functions for simplifying an inverse trigonometric expression?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Several google searches in regards to this only led me to results about trigonometric substitution in regards to integrals, not to my specific question. My education board's math book and several solution sites for my book, and my school and tutors all seem to use this rather strange method for many questions which I am struggling to intuit

For example, a question like the below:

[image]

From what I understand, you take an expression that just so happens to be similar in form to a previously taught trigonometric expression, and substitute a trigonometric function in it that just so happens to work for simplification. That is where I am confused. I have asked my tutor, and a few people I know and still am struggling to understand this

It seems arbitrary. How can we say we 'simplified' the equation and got a simpler general form if what we did involved us assuming x was a very specific trigonometric function, such that substituting any other function would NOT work?

To me it is like saying $(x+3x^2) + 2$ can be simplified to $0$, because $x + 3x^2$ always evaluates to some very special function $h(x)$, which can be represented in the special form $x + 3x^2$ to evaluate to $-2$ in all cases.

This very method seems like it would work for only a specific 'branch' right? How can one produce a general solution this way? How does it logically work?

Comment: Well if $x\in[-1/2,1/2]$ then there's a $\theta$ (not entirely unique) such that $x=\sin\theta$. We substitute this and apply some trigonometric magic to conclude. You could try to substitute anything else but probably they just wouldn't bring the solution any closer..

Comment: @Berci I am struggling to make sense of this. Why can we say x can be replaced by sin thetha just because sin thetha produces all the values in the set x belongs to?

Comment: Exactly because of that. As I said, we could try any other form (like $x=t^2-1/2$) that also covers the possible values of $x$ but then we just couldn't simplify what we'd get..

Comment: @Berci Very sorry if my question is silly but how can we know for sure that (without empirically trying out values) subbing in sin in place of x and simplifying results in the exact same answer as subbing in t^2−1/2 in place of x?

Comment: Well, it's not a trivial question. Probably if one is familiar with the applied trigonometric identity for $\sin(3\theta)$ then they might recognize that polynomial and make the substitution so that the identity can be applied. Without any preliminary hints, it's totally not immediate ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interval $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ the function $\sin(\theta)$ is almost bijective. This means that if $x\in[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ then $x$ has a correspondent $\theta$ such that $x=\sin(\theta)$. Thus you should think of $\sin(\theta)$ as being another way to write $x$.

Hence it is normal to replace $x$ by this trigonometric function. In your case it just happens that it simplifies the equation.

Comment: I dont quite understand. How can we say that this produces a general equation just because sin() is bijective in that range?

Comment: @Hash what do you mean by general equation ?

Comment: By general equation, I mean a simplified equation that happens to 'just work'. I was under the assumption that subbing in sin() and simplifying would result in an equation that only got to its current form because we specifically used sin(). How can we know whether it will provide that same simplified form for any general value of x, not just sin()?

Comment: @Hash Here there the idea is to replace $x$ by something equal to it, but presented in another form. Form example, $\sqrt(2)/2=sin(\pi/4)$. Now, that we have made the substitution $x=sin(\theta)$, we can use properties of inverse functions as shown in the above picture.  I think what confuses you is that you are not sure to obtain the "same" equations. However, this kind of transformation just changes the shape of the equation but not its solutions.

Comment: How do I logically understand how the equation shape just changes but not the solution itself? I am not able to get the concept to sink in, is there anyway to intuit the line you stated?

Comment: @Hash Think of it like cryptography: bijectiveness ensures that when I encrypt "pigs fly" as "qjht gmz", the recipient can decrypt the message using the reverse process, losslessly recovering the entire original message (because each original letter uniquely matches a new letter). BTW, the textbook is bad: for example, "solving right-hand side" is incoherent/nonsensical.

Comment: @ryang I see. So essentially since there is no loss of info , if I want, I can convert it back into the regular form? Also, what do you mean by solving the right hand side exactly? Do you mean the bit where they simplify the right hand side first? If so, why exactly is it bad? Quite a few questions do it here, and I am curious to know

Comment: @Hash 1. Yes, because the bijective substitution is a nice one-to-one correspondence. 2. Yes, you *simplify* an expression and solve an equation; you do not solve an expression...; besides, the given exercise involves proving an equality, not solving it.

Comment: @ryang I see, I have understood now almost, thank you!